# How performant are the arduinos as keyboard controllers? E.g. for a gaming application

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, usb-device, hid

Issues I'm concerned about are:

- Latency (e.g. approximately seconds between key press, and key reaching PC or OS).
- [Ghosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_(key)#Ghosting).

Comment: What's performant?

Comment: Not sure. Do you know what's the right word?  To me performant is "well performing", in a similar way "compliant" is to "compliance".

Comment: I learned something today. Interesting use!

Comment: @winny I'm not a native English speaker though.  I'm not sure if what I did is right.  My spell checker complained, but Google seems happy with my independently discovered word.

Comment: Neither am I :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which Arduino? The low-end ones don't have USB interfaces.

Latency will mostly be determined by the host's USB polling speed and the keyboard firmware's scan rate across the keyboard. Pretty much any controller will do an equally good job; it's often done by low performance 8051 chips.

Similarly, "ghosting" is an inherent problem with keyboard matrixes that must be solved by adding diodes to the scan matrix and is independent of what controller is used.

Comment: So, any arduino with USB interface will be as fast as those USB gaming keyboards?  And with enough diodes any arduino will be ghosting-free?

Comment: How do we know how fast "those USB gaming keyboards" are if you don't give any values to compare with? It also depends which USB mode is used, as newer USB protocols allow for faster poll rates than the 1ms used on older USB protocols. It also depends if you want to present the keyboard as standard HID keyboard or some other custom device you are willing to write USB drivers for your operating system.

Comment: I think what you're missing and what the people questioning 'performant' are getting at is that performance is not a yes/no question but a measure that needs numbers. I'd not expect any of the Arduinos to add more than a milisecond in processing time - but you have to get one with a "real" USB interface, not the ones with USB-serial chips on the board.

Comment: @Justme Not sure if those USB gaming KBs list any benchmarks.  But they keep claiming it.  So I wonder if anyone knows what they are doing?  And whether that is within the reach of an Arduino of a "real" USB interface?

Comment: @caveman keyboard marketing materials are just marketing. There is however a thriving home-built keyboard community you can google for, get kits from, etc who have Opinions on this. And there are libraries: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/usb/keyboard/ mentions which boards will work, "Leonardo, Esplora, Zero, Due and MKR Family"

Answer (score 1):

The performance of code running in an Arduino (even the few ones that can cope with USB output) would be worse than the perfomance of even a cheap dedicated USB-keyboard IC.

So, don't use Arduino for emulating a keyboard through USB port - it's slow and difficult.

Instead, get an old unused keyboard, get rid of the "keyboard" part (keys, flexible printed circuit, etc), and use the controller board of the keyboard (it's a tiny PCB about 8 cm x 3 cm, with three LEDs, a USB cable soldered to it, and about 20-30 connections to the keyboard flexible circuit).

Use Arduino for switch the pins of the controller board, as if a person was typing. This would be a code easier to write and it would run fast.

[link](https://www.instructables.com/id/Hacking-a-USB-Keyboard/) and [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y83jmDICLlI)

Comment: Wow neat!  But any reason why would an Arduino be slower? This seems against what @pjc50 said (from what I understand).

Comment: If the Arduino code is not worse, it will be at least just efficient as the dedicated-IC, both are the maximum speed of the USB 1.0 performance expected from a PC keyboard. The only reason for trying the Arduino option would be if you **want to learn** how to do this. If your objective is just build a MCU controlled keyboard, hacking a keyboard PCB is much easier.

Comment: I've been researching and it seems that mask rom is obsolete.. deleted the wrong comment... Well... I never did a test; it's just a feeling... I think that C/C++ arduino code, even when running in a fast Arduino, will be less efficient as the proprietary optimized low level code that possibly runs in an IC (even a low profile 8051 clone) whose only function is controlling an USB keyboard. Like [this](https://www.sigmachip.com/keyboard-controller/), [this](http://www.ene.com.tw/english/pro/ecdetail.php?pid=1) and [this](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheets2/13/135595_1.pdf).